# on click of div Collapse all the other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have 7 divs one beside the other in horizontal line.

i want to make animation when the user click on a div of them the other divs will collapse under the dive clicked.

is there any code to do it no matter what is the code that will do it?

also is the code will work if the divs in a table ?

Comment: are you using bootstrap. If so try collapse technique which is already in bootstrap

Comment: When you say "collapse", do you mean "move"? Or you want to collapse *and* move?

Comment: yes im using bootstrap
what i mean in collapse is to hide all the divs under the div clicked no matter what is the div position it may be the first one from left or in the center or the last one

Comment: Why have you just dumped your entire php file here? Post the relevant markup and then describe what you want and what you've tried. Read this first - [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<style>
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<div class="forHide">1</div>
<div class="forHide">2</div>
<div class="forHide">3</div>
<div class="forHide">4</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.forHide').on('click', function(){
    $('.forHide').addClass('hidden'); // hides all
    $(this).removeClass('hidden'); // current hide deleted
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much its working perfect

Answer (score 0):

you have to add any constant class to all div. For example look into the following code sample.

```
 <div class="all-div">first Div</div>
    <div class="all-div">second Div</div>
    <div class="all-div">third Div</div>
    <div class="all-div">fourth Div</div>
    <div class="all-div">fifth Div</div>
    <div class="all-div">sixth Div</div>
    <script>$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".all-div").on("click",function(){
    var current=this;
    $(".all-div").each(function(key,val){
          if($(val)!=$(current))$(val).hide();
          else $(val).show();
      });
    });
    });</script>
```

this is sample code. You can modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: thank you but its hide all of them on click

Comment: @musa94 Have a look into this. After a small modification it is working fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/w0051rwL/

Comment: @musa94 Only problem was != operator is not working in this case so i modified it a little bit .

 $(".all-div").on("click",function(){
    var current=this;
    $(".all-div").each(function(key,val){
          if(!$(val).is($(current)))$(val).hide();
          else $(val).show();
      });
    });
    });

Answer (score 0):

Your question with horizontal divs, and the ability to collapse with animation looks very close to accordion functionality.

I've used a jQuery plugin zAccordion to create this: https://jsfiddle.net/bc2x2e1s/3/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#boxes").zAccordion({
    width: 700,
    height: 310,
    tabWidth: 100,
    invert: true
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#boxes div {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="boxes">
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus es.
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus es.
  </div>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus es.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first of all thank you
and the fiddle is not working

Comment: Sorry, check now: https://jsfiddle.net/arslanone/bc2x2e1s/5/